# In my laravel app date is saving at mysql in '0000-00-00' format

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, date

I have to take a date range and saved into database every separate date into that range. But the date is saving like '0000-00-00' format although date is passing correctly at controller.

code my controller:

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        // dd($request->all());
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'title' => 'required|max:191',
            'start_date' => 'required',
        ]);
        
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            if($request->ajax()){ 
                return response()->json(['result'=>'error','message'=>$validator->errors()->all()]);
            }else{
                return redirect('holidays/create')
                            ->withErrors($validator)
                            ->withInput();
            }           
        }
            
      
        $startDate = new Carbon($request->start_date);
        $endDate = new Carbon($request->end_date);
        $all_dates = array();
        while ($startDate->lte($endDate)){
          $all_dates[] = $startDate->toDateString();
        
          $startDate->addDay();
        }
        // dd($all_dates);
        if(isset($request->start_date)){
            foreach($all_dates as $holdate){
                $holiday= new Holiday();
                $holiday->title = $request->input('title');
                $holiday->start_date = $holdate;
                $holiday->end_date = $request->input('end_date');
                $holiday->company_id = company_id();
                // dd($holiday);
                $holiday->save();

            }
        }

      
       
        
        //Set Related Data
        
        if(! $request->ajax()){
           return redirect('holidays')->with('success', _lang('Saved Sucessfully'));
        }else{
           return response()->json(['result'=>'success','action'=>'store','message'=>_lang('Saved Sucessfully'),'data'=>$account]);
        }
    }
```

form at my blade page

{{ csrf_field() }}
            
            
              
                {{ _lang('Title').'('._lang('Holiday For').')'}}

```
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">{{ _lang('Start Date') }}</label>                      
            <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" name="start_date" value="{{ old('start_date') }}" required>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">{{ _lang('End Date') }}</label>                        
            <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" name="end_date" value="{{ old('end_date') }}">
          </div>
        </div>
                
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger">{{ _lang('Reset') }}</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">{{ _lang('Save') }}</button>
          </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Can you also provide the related migration?

Comment: `$holiday->start_date = 2023-04-13;` - the right part of that is not a date, it's a math operation - the result of which is 2006.

Comment: `foreach($all_dates as $holdate)` - you are not even using that `$holdate` anywhere inside that loop.

Comment: actually I have used $holiday->start_date = $holdate but I posted it in a rush while testing my code whether it takes static data or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my Holiday mode I declared a function like this

class Holiday extends Model
{
protected $table = 'holidays';

```
 public function setStartDateAttribute($value)
 {
     return Carbon::parse($value)->format('Y-m-d');
 }
```

}

Because of this setStartDateAttribute() method my start_date is getting null value. now I commented out this method.